# Button that zooms div (containing image and canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/masterlup/tqun5sjd/),  (check out zoomInOut button.)

For my drawing app, i need a button, so that on press the content inside of div `#layerTown`(contains 1 img and 2 canvas) gets zoomed 2x the size. (It will get pixelated, thats OKAY!!!). On the next press it should go back to natural view (zoom:1;).

After googling i came up the two approaches:

1. in css (how can i hook it up to a button here? :active isnt doing the job)

   ```
   #layerTown {
       zoom:2;
   }
   ```

This was very close to what i want, but the mouse was very "jumpy" and "strange" as i was approaching the bottom part of the canvas.

2. using css inside of js (look jsfiddle line 79). Comes out very bad. Look at the fiddle.

```
var layerTown = document.querySelector("#layerTown");
var setZoom = function() {
    if (!zoom) {
        zoom = true;
        layerTown.style.cssText = "zoom:2;";
    } else {
        zoom = false;
        layerTown.style.cssText = "zoom:1;";
    }
}
```

How can i get this button to work properly, so that the "human" just gets zoomed and the mouse still works fine?

Comment: Fiddle is empty,you might want to run save

Comment: Inside #layerTown transition: transform .3s; transform-origin: center center; and transform: scale(2);


The human runs left out of the window. i can get him to return right by drawing the debug console of chrome to the left. The mouse issues are not prominent anymore with that approach. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the valuable help of @sdvnksv and @Mr Bones. I was able to find a solution: [New fiddle with Zoom](https://jsfiddle.net/masterlup/tqun5sjd/1/)

To keep the "human" in place i added a mini transparent square. (thnx to Mr Bones). Dont really understand why i need that mini-square.

css

```
#layerTown {
    transition: transform .3s;
    transform-origin: center center;

    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)";
}

#layerTown.active {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

Then i used jQuery anyways (wasnt too complicated) - (Thanks to sdvnksv)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#zoomInOut').on('click', function() {
        $('#layerTown').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Thanks for your input. It really looks nice!

Comment: I highly recommend against using jQuery for just that one event. You're loading ~84Kb file for just an event binding that you can do with pure JS

Answer (score 1):

You can use css transforms:

```
#layerTown {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

#layerTown.active {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

Then add an active class to the layer with JS on button click:

```
$(button).on('click', function() {
  $('#layerTown').toggleClass('active');
});
```

(this is  a jQuery solution though).

Comment: as im very new i havent touched on jQuery yet. As it seem very strong and popular i will dive in.

Comment: @AndreElrico The answer is not about jQuery, but CSS transforms. You can toggle the `active` class with pure JS too.

Answer (score 1):

This one is using pure Js and CSS

```js
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector("#layerTown").classList.toggle("active")
});
```

```css
#layerTown {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform-origin: center center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#layerTown.active {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div id="layerTown">
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<button id="button">Click Me!</button>
```

This one is using pure CSS

```css
#layerTown {
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform-origin: center center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#layerTown:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div id="layerTown"></div>
```